# Global setMaxResult in JPA Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, limit, sybase

App uses JPA Hibernate and database is Sybase; it has several search screens for each domain type. I understand that query.setMaxResult(limit) will prevent the query from returning too much. In the case of Sybase, I believe it would be translated to use:

```
select top n from table --n = limit
```

However, **is there a global setting** that I can configure so that all queries of the app will recognize this limit, what is it and how to use?

Follow up question is, I will then configure  1 or 2 queries to have their setMaxResults to be say limits+1000, doing the query.setMaxResult(limit+1000) will **override the global setting** correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no global setting, and you really don't want such a setting. Indeed, `setMaxResults()` does not make sense for a whole lot of queries.

In particular, if a query loads an entity and at least one to-many association, `setMaxResults()` should not be used. It limits the number of rows returned from the database, and not the number of entities returned from the query. So, imagine you have entities A and B with the following associations:

```
A1 - B1
A1 - B2
A1 - B3
A2 - B4
A2 - B5
A2 - B6
```

And imaging you execute the following query: `select a from A a left join fetch a.b`. If you set the max results to 4, the returned rows might be

```
A1 - B1
A1 - B2
A1 - B3
A2 - B4
```

and you will end up with the A1 entity with all its Bs, and with an A2 entity with only one of its Bs instead of all 3.

Nothing forbids you to implement some sort of reusable query template which automatically applies max results, though. But applying it blindly to all queries is wrong.

Comment: Hi JB, thanks for pointing this out! I did not realize this would affect the entity associations. In that case, does it leave me no choice but to visit each Query and call setMaxResults(limit) for all 7 search dao (1 for each search screen)? Or perhaps can this be done via AOP or filtering, though it happens in the DAO layer...?

Comment: You only have 7? Then definitely visite each query.

Comment: So..... the answer is that there's no way to do this in JPA? (I think the BatchSize annotation would work in hibernate). But that's pretty depressing if JPA can't